# How do I crop using relative offsets in ImageMagick?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, crop, imagemagick-convert

For example, this does not work:

```
convert -crop '69%x27%+3%+13%' +repage source.jpg cropped.jpg
```

It does not result in an error, but the offset is ignored.
Apparently the offset in a geometry can only be in pixels?

How do I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
convert -crop $(convert source.jpg -format "%[fx:int(w*0.69)]x%[fx:int(h*0.27)]+%[fx:int(0.03*w)]+%[fx:int(0.13*h)]"  info:) +repage source.jpg cropped.jpg
```

Try running the section inside the `$()` on its own to see how that generates what you need for the outer command...

```
convert source.jpg -format "%[fx:int(w*0.69)]x%[fx:int(h*0.27)]+%[fx:int(0.03*w)]+%[fx:int(0.13*h)]"  info:
```

If I run that part of the command on an image 100x100 pixels, I get this

```
69x27+3+13
```